# Binomial theorem proof...

Tags: calculus

[image]
The LHS does not equal the RHS when $x=1$ please help. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Instead of doing $\frac {d^2}{dx^2}$, do this: $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right).$$